# How to stop minute cron job?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a program written in python,my program scrapes a value from some financial website every minute and pushes that value into my DB.My program takes like 1 or maximum 1.5 seconds to do this job. I have set a cron job to call my program every minute. I need to run my program in this way everyday from 09AM to 04PM. Now sometimes I may have to stop my program to kill the program at any time between 09AM to 4PM. How can I do this?

According to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313033/how-can-i-see-stop-current-running-crontab-tasks)
I tried `ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | grep -A20 "cron$"`  and I was unable to find my program in the list since it completes it's work in seconds.

Referring to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232144/how-to-stop-a-currently-running-cron-job) I tried `/etc/init.d/cron stop` and `pkill cron` which kills all cron jobs which I don't want. I am running this cron in ubuntu linux .Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the program so it runs only if a particular file exists. Remove the file if you need to stop the program. (Or have it run only if the file *doesn't* exist, and `touch` the file to stop the program.)

If you're not able to modify the program, you can execute a shell `if` statement as a cron command.

Comment: I think, I can even use DB to create a some sort of flags. I can modify my program in such a way that my program executes only if flag is set to to execute then execute or else my program shouldn't execute. Whenever i want my program to stop executing I just have to set the flag not to execute.

Comment: Thanq, This is one good solution i had in back of my mind. But stil wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: @ChiyaanSuraj DB controlled execution is definitely the best solution, if you use DB in your script. If you use Oracle, you can take DBMS_SCHEDULER as alternative to cron.

Comment: Ok. So there's no solution like killing that specific cron job then?

Comment: @ChiyaanSuraj: There's no process associated with a single cron job, so there's nothing to kill. Another possible option is to modify the crontab, but that requires access to the user account that created it.

Answer (score 0):

simply rename the script name, so it will not be executed

Answer (score -1):

Is it feasible to include a date time check within the program? And it won't run if before 9AM or after 4PM?

The following should also work:

```
* 9-15 * * * script.sh
0 16 * * * script.sh
```

To switch: perhaps have it read from a config/detect the presence of a file (acting as a flag) to determine whether or not to run.

Comment: ya i have included date time check within my program and it won't run before 9am and after 4pm.

Comment: That will run every minute from 09:00 to 16:59. To run from 09:00 to 16:00 you need two lines, one to run from 09:00 to 15:59 and another to run just at 16:00.